# How do I actually delete the node(s)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, delete-operator

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-leaves-of-binary-tree/):

> Given the root of a binary tree, collect a tree's nodes as if you were doing this: 
> a. Collect all the leaf nodes. 
> b. Remove all the leaf nodes. 
> c. Repeat until the tree is empty.

[image]

> For the input `root = [1,2,3,4,5]` (image above), the output should be: `[[4,5,3],[2],[1]]`.

This comes down to finding the height of each node of the tree:

```cpp
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> m;
    
    int dfs(TreeNode* root) {
        if(!root) return -1;
        
        int l=dfs(root->left);
        int r=dfs(root->right);
        int height=max(l,r)+1;
        
        if(height==m.size()) m.push_back({});
        
        m[height].push_back(root->val);
        
        //delete root;
        
        return height;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> findLeaves(TreeNode* root) {
        dfs(root);
        
        return m;
    }
};
```

The above code gets accepted, but that is because the OJ does not *actually check* if the nodes were deleted or not.  My question is, how do I delete the nodes?  Specifically:

a. If I add delete (commented line above), I get a runtime error; 
b. I cannot just set `root=nullptr` like the Java folks, since C++ does not have garbage collection by default and so the `root` node would not really be *deleted* (the memory would continue to be occupied).
c. I don't think we can delete the `root` node anywhere else.

So how do I go about *actually* deleting the node?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in the code is showing how/whether the nodes were dynamically allocated. So there is no way to know whether/how they ought to be deleted. So there is nothing you can do about it anyway.

Comment: @user17732522, unfortunately the code on the OJ does not show how the objects are created; but my understanding is that the OJ dynamically allocates them using the `new` operator.

Comment: You don't have to delete the nodes.

Comment: Then, assuming you know that it is your responsibility to delete the nodes and is not done by code outside your control, you ought to call `delete` on every single node once, since the node class doesn't have a destructor that would take care of deleting its children.

Comment: @DavidG, I don't _have_ to, but I _want_ to.

Comment: @user17732522, yes, so my question is where in the code do I call the `delete` operator: I don't see a correct place for it.

Comment: If you used `operator new` to allocate a node, you should use `delete node`.

Comment: When you set the link field to `nullptr`, after removing a node, you should delete the node.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, yes, but where?  At its current place, it throws runtime error.  And I don't see anywhere else where we can `delete root`.

Comment: @Someone When backtracking in the DFS (as you tried). Also, whether or not `delete root` (for the actual root of the tree) is correct depends on whether the root was also allocated with `new`. You say that `delete root;` gives a runtime error, so obviously that doesn't seem to be the case. As I said, without knowing exactly how memory was allocated, you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: @user17732522, the run-time error is "AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free", so I guess the issue is I am trying to reference it after the memory has been freed.  But I don't see where else we could `delete`.

Comment: @Someone I don't see anything in your code that would cause that. It must be caused by code we don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your placement of `delete` is correct, but since we don't know how `root` is allocated we can't be sure whether `delete` is *logically* correct. BTW, `delete` deallocates the memory but it doesn't remove the pointers themselves. You can do `root->left = root->right = nullptr` to take care of that. Also, have `findLeaves` take a reference to the pointer and set `root` to `nullptr` after the call to `dfs()` to fully delete the tree.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it: are you suggesting setting the pointers to null (only)?  That wouldn't deallocate the memory in C++, right?

Comment: @Someone In addition to `delete`ing the nodes, you should also set them to `nullptr`. So all you need to do is put `root->left = root->right = nullptr` above the `delete root` line, and also do the other thing mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Someone `delete` deallocates the memory. But the pointers themselves will still point to the deallocated address afterwards. That's why we set them to `nullptr`. So it's clear the memory is no longer valid to use.